# Integral Basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{i})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integral-basis

I understand the Integral basis of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{i})$  is:  $\{1,i,\sqrt{i},i\sqrt{i}\}$ .

To find out this basis, have i each time to compute the discriminant?

Any reference book or notes where explains it in a simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

$x^4+1\bmod p$ is coprime with its derivative thus separable whenever $p\ne 2$.

Thus $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{i}]=\Bbb{Z}[x^4]/(x^4+1)$ is ramified only at $2$. Thus every prime ideal above $p\ne 2$ is invertible.

Above $2$ there is only one prime ideal which is $(2,\sqrt{i}-1)$ and $(2,\sqrt{i}-1)^4=(2)$.

Thus every non-zero prime ideal is invertible, it is a Dedekind domain, whence it has to be $O_{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{i})}$.

Comment: Thanks reuns. Very hard for me, but it encourage me to learn more

Answer (score 3):

There are several papers on the "Computation of an Integral Basis of Quartic Number Fields". In particular, one by [El Fadil](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.2786.pdf) for all quartic number field $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, where the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is of the form
$$
X^4+aX+b\in \Bbb Z[X].
$$
Clearly $a=0$ and $b=1$ for $\alpha=\sqrt{i}$. The paper first computes $p$-integral bases and at the last page is is said, that one can recover a triangular integral basis from different triangular $p$-integral
basis for all p as follows - see Proposition $2.2$.

Another reference is [Integral Bases for Quartic Fields with Quadratic Subfields](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X85710360), which also gives the result, i.e., $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb Q(\sqrt{i})}=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{i}]$.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich for papers and references

Comment: You are welcome.